# PID control for UAV

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, pid-control, aircraft-design, stability

I'm working on a deltawing model airplane where I want to implement a PID controller to stabilize the pitch, roll and yaw (which are only controlled by two elevons). However, I don't know too much about the subject. I only working once on a position control PID for a robot, but an aircraft is a bit more complicated. I figured out that I'd start with one rotation first, the pitch since it has the most disturbances during flight.

I figured out that I should first look at the system. The input would be a set point controlled by an external RC controller, which goes through the controller and plant and result into a rotation of the servo motors controlling the elevons. The elevons then give a pitch moment that should lead to the correct set point pitch angle.

So how do I go about designing a stabilizing PID controller for a system like this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is a HUGE topic, I spent most of my masters degree working on almost this exact problem. In order to control a system you first really need to understand it. Look at the equations for flight motion, 6 as a minimum, that's your plant. Location of sensors is also a big issue. To get a more specific answer you may want to refine your question. How to design a PID for aircraft isn't a "Just do this" type of problem there is a fair bit of trial, error and research that is required. An awesome problem and super fun, but not something you're likely going to get a simple answer for on here.